# Amalgamate four regexes into one?

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Below is a list of strings I need to evaluate against and the four regexes that do the job.

```
^99[0-3,5,7-9,A-E,I-S,V-Z]$
^99A[C,E]$
^9A[A-D,F-G,I-N,P,S-U]$"
^9B[B,E-H]$"
```

Although the four work I'd much rather have just one.
How do I merge four into one?

```
990
991
992
993
995
997
998
999
99A
99AC
99AE
99B
99C
99D
99E
99I
99J
99K
99L
99M
99N
99O
99P
99Q
99R
99S
99V
99W
99X
99Y
99Z
9AA
9AB
9AC
9AD
9AF
9AG
9AI
9AJ
9AK
9AL
9AM
9AN
9AP
9AS
9AT
9AU
9BB
9BE
9BF
9BG
9BH
```

I couldn't post this because I was getting a warning that my post was mainly code so I've added this text as a bit of padding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commas inside the character class and use a capturing or non-capturing group with `|` OR operator.

```
^(99[0-357-9A-EI-SV-Z]|99A[CE]|9A[A-DF-GI-NPS-U]|9B[BE-H])$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qU7nN0/8)